# Diagonalise a matrix and show the formula

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, diagonalization

I have diagonlised P to get
$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

however am unsure on how to proceed, would appreciate any help!

By diagonalising P by a transformation of similarity, show that

$$    e^{Pt} = (I_3 - P^2) + P \sinh( t) + P^2 \cosh(t)$$

when

$P$ is the matrix
$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
0 &1 &0
\end{matrix}\right)$$
and where $I_3$ is the identity matrix of a $3\times3$

Comment: Downvoted for seemingly deliberate vandalism of your own post. Please ping me if someone rolls back to the old version.

Comment: @NilsMatthes I've rolled it back.

Comment: @jim: thanks. undone my vote

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You do not need to diagonalize, actually. Simply compute and observe that
$$
P^3=P.
$$
To figure this out, of course, one might need to compute the eigenvalues: $-1,0,1$. So actually, $P^3-P=0$ is nothing but Cayley-Hamilton.

Note that
$$
P^0=I_3\qquad P^{2n}=P^2\qquad P^{2n-1}=P\qquad\forall n\geq 1.
$$

So
$$
e^{tP}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^nP^n}{n!}=I_3+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}P^2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}P
$$
$$
=I_3 +(\cosh t-1)P^2+\sinh t P=I_3-P^2+\sinh tP+\cosh tP^2.
$$

Note: if you do absolutely need to diagonalize, go ahead and write
$$
P=AQA^{-1}
$$
where $Q$ is the diagonalized form you found.

Then all the previous argument holds for $Q$ and you find
$$
e^{tQ}=I_3 +(\cosh t-1)Q^2+\sinh t Q=I_3-Q^2+\sinh tQ+\cosh tQ^2.
$$
It only remains to see that
$$
AQ^nA^{-1}=(AQA^{-1})^n=P^n\qquad\forall n\geq 0
$$
to deduce that
$$
e^{tP}=Ae^{tQ}A^{-1}=I_3 +(\cosh t-1)P^2+\sinh t P=I_3-P^2+\sinh tP+\cosh tP^2.
$$

Comment: Hi @Julien thanks for your help that looks great! Do you know any other method to get to this answer without using Cayley Hamilton theory? Thank you

Comment: @Jay What do you mean: without Cayley-Hamilton theory? Without diagonalization?

Comment: I don't think julien used the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Jay There you go. No diagonalization. What do you think?

Comment: You do need to diagonalize, if the problem statement begins, "By diagonalising $P$...."

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure. But it's still useless.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note that I did it like this first, using the diagonalized form given by the OP. But then the OP asked me a question which seemed to mean that he/she was curious about an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps it will bridge the apparent gap if we note that if $P,Q$ are similar matrices, then they satisfy exactly the same polynomial equations.  My guess is the problem suggest the diagonalized form (which is ambiguously also labeled $P$ in the Question) because checking the satisfaction of a polynomial equation can be done diagonal-entry-by-diagonal-entry.

Comment: @hardmath What gap?

Comment: @julien: By "gap" I mean your difference of opinion as to diagonalization being unneeded or "still useless".

Comment: @hardmath Ah, ok. I was exaggerating a little bit when I said diagonalization is useless. Like I said in my answer, the natural steps consist in computing the characteristic polynomial first. Like you would do to diagonalize anyway. But then you obser the Cayley-Hamilton gives this neat relation which allows to compute the exponential easily. If there was no such nice relation, diagonalization would be the way. But since it's here, we should use it. That's what I was taught and it's pretty helpful, so I can't help it.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

By diagonalising P by a transformation of similarity, show that

$$    e^{Pt} = (I_3 - P^2) + P \sinh( t) + P^2 \cosh(t)$$

If we diagonalize the matrix $P$, we arrive at:

$$P = S J S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Note: $\cosh t = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t} + e^{t}) ~ \text{and} ~ \sinh t = \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t} + e^{t}) ~\text{and}~ P^{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Using this diagonalization, the matrix exponential is given by:

$$\displaystyle e^{Pt} = e^{S J S^{-1} t} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} e^{-1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & e^{t}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t}) \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t}) & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t})\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t}) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t})\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t}) & 0\end{bmatrix} = (I_3 - P^2) + P \sinh( t) + P^2 \cosh(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t}) & -1 + \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t}) \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t}) & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t})\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2}(-e^{-t}+e^{t}) & \frac{1}{2}(e^{-t}+e^{t})\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice work! All the formatting, yikes! + 1

Comment: @amWhy: I recall that one and it was a nightmare writing up, but not the worst one I've had! thx!

Comment: I don't get how some users "whip these up" in no time at all!!

Comment: That's a great idea, Amzoti!

Comment: Of course, all sort of matrix variants are in there as are the special characters I use often and then some of the ones I use infrequently that are harder to find. It really helps me to write things up faster and I use notepad++ as my scratch pad - a really handy text processor.